# Qt5.9.9+Vs2017 encountered a character set problem

Tags: c++, qt

As the following codes:

```cpp
CDllLoader::Load(const char* Dll, bool* pLoadError /*=NULL*/)
{
  // load the dll
  m_hDLL = LoadLibrary(Dll);
}
```

But I encounter following problems:

```bash
Cannot convert parameter 1 from “const char *to “LPCWSTR”    ...\dllloader.cpp    68
```

Besides, another code block has similar problem as:

```cpp
CDllLoader::HandleFatalError(const char* Dll)
{
    // create a buffer for the error-message
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    // create the message text
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, GetLastError(),
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL);
    // copy the error-message in a string
    std::string Text((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf);//Corresponding to row 185
    // free's the error-message-buffer
    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    // add the dll-name to the error-string
    Text += Dll;
    // exit the application with a error-messagebox
    FatalAppExit(0, Text.c_str());//Corresponding to row 16
}
```

And the problems are:

```bash
Error   C2664    “std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)”: Cannot convert parameter 1 from “LPCTSTR” to “std::initializer_list<_Elem>”    micro_epsilon1    d:\code_rela\micro_epsilon1\micro_epsilon1\dllloader.cpp    185
```

And:

```bash
Error    C2664    “void FatalAppExitW(UINT,LPCWSTR)”: Cannot convert parameter 2 from“const _Elem *” to “LPCWSTR”    micro_epsilon1    d:\code_rela\micro_epsilon1\micro_epsilon1\dllloader.cpp    191
```

According to the online suggestions, it should be a character set problem. I have set the character set to 'use multi-byte character set' here, but the above error cannot be resolved.
The above similar code has no problem in the console application as long as it is set to 'use multi-byte character set'. Could you please tell me how to solve it?"

Comment: Use [LoadLibraryA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya).

Comment: With `Qt` you may want to use [QLibrary](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlibrary.html) instead of LoadLibrary although then you probably don't want to use the `CDllLoader` class at all.

Comment: Thank you PaulMcKenzie. Your advice really solved my problem, but I encountered similar problems in another code block, and I have edited the above, please check it again if available, thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know why LoadLibraryA should have been used?  If you do, then `FatalAppExitW` suffers from the same issue.  Did you see if there is a `FatalAppExitA` exists?  But the bottom line is that you should be aware of the string types you are using, and making sure that you are calling the correct functions that match the string parameters you are calling them with.

Comment: Also, the excessive casting of strings just to get the compiler to "behave" is not recommended.  If your code that handles strings is full of casts all over the place, that is a good sign you are using the incorrect string types, and runtime issues will surface.  Also, using `LPTSTR`, or `LPCTSTR` does not mean they are non-wide pointers to strings.  Assuming they are (like in your code) is not correct.  Using `std::string` may not be correct -- if the LPTSTR or LPCSTR is actually pointing to a Unicode string, then `std::wstring` should be used, not `std::string`.